# how to decode JSON array in php

Tags: php, json

am new to php, I'm struggle to get right data from my JSON object. I wan't to get the series_id, name, units and updates from [this JSON link](http://api.eia.gov/category/?api_key=FA92066C073D681DD8795C40F72E3B4B&category_id=40445)

#### Here is sample JSON:

```
{
   "request":{
      "category_id":40445,
      "command":"category"
   },
   "category":{
      "category_id":"40445",
      "parent_category_id":"40920",
      "name":"Btu",
      "notes":"",
      "childcategories":[

      ],
      "childseries":[
         {
            "series_id":"SEDS.PATCB.RI.A",
            "name":"All petroleum products total consumption, Rhode Island",
            "f":"A",
            "units":"Billion Btu",
            "updated":"22-APR-13 12.40.53 PM"
         },
         {
            "series_id":"SEDS.PATCB.TN.A",
            "name":"All petroleum products total consumption, Tennessee",
            "f":"A",
            "units":"Billion Btu",
            "updated":"22-APR-13 12.40.53 PM"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

#### Here is my attempt so far:

```
<?php

 $API_url ='http://api.eia.gov/category/?api_key=FA92066C073D681DD8795C40F72E3B4B&category_id=40445';

 $string .= file_get_contents($API_url);// get json content
 $json_result = json_decode($string, true);//json decoder

 foreach ($json_result as $value) {

    foreach ($value as $key => $entry) {

        print_r($entry);

    }

 }

?>
```

How would I go about getting all the series_id, name, units and updates from the array?

Comment: What is it? `$string .=` I mean `.=` why you're using it here?

Comment: You have to iterate over the array `$json_result['category']['childseries']`.

Comment: Have a look at the **documentation** to learn how to access arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

Comment: @FelixKling, I attempted iterating over the array, when i var_dump() the series_id i get NULL

Comment: You probably did something wrong. Please post your code.

Comment: Ur right i did  do something wrong, thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can directly access the array you need with scopes `$json_result['category']['childseries']` and then loop into it

```
 foreach ($json_result['category']['childseries'] as $data) {
     foreach($data as $key => $val) {
        echo "$key=>$val" . "<br>";
    }
 }
```

This will outout

```
series_id=>SEDS.PATCB.RI.A
name=>All petroleum products total consumption, Rhode Island
f=>A
units=>Billion Btu
updated=>22-APR-13 12.40.53 PM
series_id=>SEDS.PATCB.TN.A
name=>All petroleum products total consumption, Tennessee
f=>A
units=>Billion Btu
updated=>22-APR-13 12.40.53 PM
series_id=>SEDS.PATCB.NY.A 
//and so on
```

#### [Live Sample](http://ideone.com/2s7wPO)

Comment: Thanks,can't believe how easy that was. thanks alot XD :D

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```
foreach($json_result['category']['childseries'] as $value) {
     echo $value["series_id"], $value["name"], $value["units"], $value["updated"]; 
}
```

If you look at the json structure you'll see that `childseries` is inside `category`. Therefore, `$json_result['category']['childseries']` is the way to access the array you want. Simply loop through it to get the data you want.

Comment: tried your code it works!, Thanks alot for your help :D